# What exactly is a Content Delivery Platform?

Tags: networking, streaming, cdn

I ran across this Wikipedia article on [Content Delivery Platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_platform) which describes them as:

> ...a software as a service (SaaS) content service, similar to a content management system (CMS), that utilizes embedded software code to deliver web content. Instead of the installation of software on client servers, a CDP feeds content through embedded code snippets, typically via JavaScript widget, Flash widget or server-side Ajax.

So I'm fully aware of CDNs, what they are, and how they work (from the consumer's point of view), but the above description of these "CDPs" is just vague and ambiguous to me:

- "*...that utilizes embedded software code...*", "*...feeds content through embedded code snippets...*" : **what in the world does this mean?!?** What is this "*embedded code*"?!? Do they mean that CDPs are like networks of RaspberryPis or other embedded devices/SoCs?
- How would these "embedded code snippets" interact with JavaScript widgets?

Comment: a CDP is the software that CDNs use to administer their content and allow web developers to utilize the CDN in their applications. For instance this page includes javascript that makes use of `ajax.googleapis.com` for search and voting buttons. the embedded code is the javascript that asks our browsers to send requests to the google apis. These "widgets" tell our browsers to call service layer implementations deployed on the CDN via SOAP, REST, etc, to run code on the CDN and pipe the results back to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content Delivery platforms are platforms to deliver content. Take for instance this website as an example. On the right hand side, there is content that is delivered to you based on this Question as being related. Most content delivery platforms are used for advertising, while on some websites, they are used to deliver additional content to you based on what you are reading on their website and that content could either be on their website, or another website with something relating to what you are reading or looking at etc.

As Frank Thomas said as well, that is another form of Content Delivery Platform, the ones that run on the CDN's themselves. But do note, not all CDP's run on CDN's